# how to calculate Average of purchases of distinct items in the session using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with 3 columns: session id, item id and class. In the class column, 0 represents 'not purchased' and 1 represents 'purchased'.

```
> data
    session id        item id   class
      1                 1         0
      1                 1         0
      1                 1         0
      2                 1         1
      2                 2         0
      3                 1         0
      3                 0         1
      3                 3         1
      3                 2         0
```

I would like to to calculate the average number of purchases of distinct items for each unique session id. in SessionID 1 contain only one unique item and 0 purchase so avg is 0/1=0, session id 2 contain 1 purchase and 2 unique items so avg will be 1/2=0.5 and session id 3 contain 2 purchases and 4 unique items so avg will be 2/4=0.5. The results would look like this:

```
>  result   
session id       avg
   1             0/1=0
   2             0.5
   3             0.5
```

I have tried this till now:

```
data %>% 
   group_by(session_id) %>% 
   summarise(avg = ifelse(length(Class==1))/length(unique(item_id)))
```

but got the error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>         Evaluation error: argument "yes" is missing, with no default.
>   how can i solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sum` to calculate total `purchase` and `n_distinct` to get unique `item_id`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(session_id) %>%
  summarise(avg = sum(class)/n_distinct(item_id))

#   session_id   avg
#       <int> <dbl>
#1          1   0  
#2          2   0.5
#3          3   0.5
```